# Sequential Multi-Threading

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2010, tfilestream

I wanna build Multi-Threaded procedure for the following code, but not able to correctly build it. I tried using Semaphore to sequentially complete the code but it only executed the `myStream2.CopyFrom(myStream1, StrToInt64('$' + SL1[(i - 1)]));` part which comes under **else** part. The problem presents is that  if we restore those streams into output filestream (mystream2) haphazardly, the file will corrupt.

Can anyone help me  please.

```
  for i := 1 to SL1.Count do
  begin
    if Length(SL1[i - 1]) > 12 then
    begin
      TempDir := SrcDir + 'temp_' +
              IntToHex(Random(2147483647) + Random(2147483647), 8) + '\';
      ForceDirectories(TempDir);
      for k := 1 to 2 do
      begin
        tempfile := TempDir + IntToHex((i - 1), 8) + '.tmp' + IntToStr(k);
        fs := TFileStream.Create(tempfile, fmCreate or fmShareExclusive);
        fs.CopyFrom(myStream1, StrToInt64('$' + DecodeRefStr(SL1[(i - 1)])[k]));
        fs.Free;
      end;
      ExecAndWait(SrcDir + 'process.exe', Method + ' ' + '"' + TempDir +
                  IntToHex((i - 1), 8) + '.tmp1' + '" "' + TempDir +
                  IntToHex((i - 1), 8) + '.tmp2' + '" "' + TempDir +
                  IntToHex((i - 1), 8) + '.tmp4' + '"', TempDir, 
                  True,  True);
      tempfile := TempDir + IntToHex((i - 1), 8) + '.tmp4';
      fs := TFileStream.Create(tempfile, fmOpenRead);
      myStream2.CopyFrom(fs, 0);
      fs.Free;
      TDirectory.Delete(TempDir, True);
    end
    else
      myStream2.CopyFrom(myStream1, StrToInt64('$' + SL1[(i - 1)]));
    end;
    myStream1.Free;
    myStream2.Free;
```

Comment: If you need to *sequentially complete the code*, then it is not a good fit for a multi-threaded solution. Threads should be able to run in parallel, without a dependence on the order that things are done. What do you think you're going to accomplish using multiple threads here?

Comment: Well, I was thinking how those multithreaded LZMA & stuff worked..They do the same thing, process multiple buffers at a same time but end up combining them sequentially...What if we can store the output until its done in memory & sequentially add it in final FS.