# Filestream Pointers

Tags: filestream, delphi-2010

I need to copy many small file streams into one file stream. Each file stream carries its own designated position, i.e. FS1 goes firstly, then FS2 and so on. But while multi-threading the program, the thread which finishes the processing firstly adds it firstly which causes errors.

Is there any way that we can define its position so that no matter what sequence we add them, they will get in the right place??

I tried this by creating many headers before hand so that the file streams will replace those headers, but searching for those headers just slows down the program.

This question is in continuation to my last one, as First processedFS jumps (Copies) first, so we need to define location where it will be copied.

Please refer to this question:

[Sequential MT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564672/sequential-multi-threading)

Comment: It's surely going to be possible to solve your problem. You'd need a clear statement of the problem first though. It seems unlikely that multi-threading disk access can lead to performance gains. Perhaps you are over complicating.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple threads write to the same file *stream* at the same time without wrapping it with a synchronization lock, and you would also need to re-seek the stream back and forth depending on which thread needs to write to it at any given moment, so it writes at the correct offset within the file. That is a lot of overhead.

You can, however, have multiple threads use different file streams to write to the same *file* at the same time, provided the sharing rights between the streams are compatible to allow concurrent writing and preserve data.  Pre-size the file to the desired length, then divide up sections of that length amongst the threads as needed. Give each thread its own stream to the target file, first seeking to the appropriate start offset of its assigned section. Then each thread can write to its respective stream normally, without having to synch with the other threads or re-seek its stream.  Just make sure each thread does not exceed the bounds of its assigned section within the file so it does not overwrite another thread's data.